# Pcl Library and Rviz

Tags: kinect, rviz, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,
I'm new about ROS. I wrote a c++ file usign the pcl library which let me to keep me different pointclouds from the kinect, elaborate them and concatenate them in order to make a 3d reconstruction of the room. I'm able now to see the merging of the pointcloud on the openniVisualizer. Now I would like to do the same, but I would like to publish the point cloud on ROS Visualizer.
Is it possible?
if yes, how can I do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232338/pcl-library-and-rviz/) by [almosca](https://answers.ros.org/users/22088/almosca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2016-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have PCL pointclouds and you want to publish them so rviz can visualize them, you can do so directly. See: http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros#Publishing_point_clouds

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1